# c++ Postfix-Notation Evaluator using stacks

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

My Task is to create a postfix calculator but the problem is that I can't compare Token to anything. I know that the pseudo code for evaluating a post fix is this and im trying to do my program based on that:

from make file:

test: build/infix_calculator build/postfix_calculator build/tokenize

./build/tokenize "2 3 4 + *"

./build/postfix_calculator "2 3 4 + *"

./build/tokenize "2 * (3 + 4)"

./build/infix_calculator "2 * (3 + 4)"

```
for ( each character ch in the string) 
{ 
if (ch is an operand) 
Push the value of the operand ch onto the stack
else // ch is an operator named op
 { 
// Evaluate and push the result 
 operand2 = top of stack
Pop the stack
 operand1 = top of stack
Pop the stack
 result = operand1 op operand2 
Push result onto the stack
 } 
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated

Heres link to online gdb to see it in person:

https://onlinegdb.com/BkIkaPzBO

Error:
src/PostfixCalculator.cpp:15:19: error: no match for 'operator>=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<Token >::value_type {aka Token}' and 'char')
if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){

src/PostfixCalculator.cpp:15:39: error: no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<Token >::value_type {aka Token}' and 'char')
if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){

src/PostfixCalculator.cpp:16:24: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<Token >::value_type {aka Token}' and 'char')
s.push(tokens[i] - '0');

```
/**
 * @file PostfixCalculator.cpp
 */
 #include "PostfixCalculator.h"
 #include<stack>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stack>
 #include<string>


double PostfixCalculator::eval(std::vector<Token> tokens) {
  std::stack<double>s;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++){
    if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){
      s.push(tokens[i] - '0');
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
/**
 * @file PostfixCalculator.h
 */
#ifndef POSTFIX_CALCULATOR_H
#define POSTFIX_CALCULATOR_H

#include<vector>

#include "EvalInterface.h"

class PostfixCalculator : public EvalInterface<double>
{
public:
    double eval(std::vector<Token> expr);
};

#endif
```

```
/**
 * @file Token.h
 */
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H
#include <iostream>

/**
 * Tag represents a categories of token types
 */
enum Tag { OPERATOR, OPERAND, LPAREN, RPAREN };

/**
 * @brief Operator represents types of binary operations
 */
enum Operator { ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE };

/**
 * @brief A data structure to represent a token parsed from a string.
 */
struct Token {
    /** a numeric value -- only valid if the tag is OPERAND */
    double d;
    /** an operator type -- only valid if the tag is OPERATOR */
    Operator o;
    /** the category of the token */
    Tag tag;
};

/**
 * @brief convert an Operator to a std::string
 * @param o the operator
 * @return a string representation of the operator
 */
std::string opToString(Operator o);

/**
 * @brief An overloaded stream insertion operator for the Token type.
 * @param os the output stream object
 * @param t the Token to be inserted into the stream
 * @return the same ostream that was passed in
 */
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Token& t);

/**
 * @brief parse a string representing a simple arithmetic expression
 * into sequence of tokens.
 * @param s the string to parse
 * @return the result of parsing the string into tokens
 */
std::vector<Token> tokenize(std::string s);

#endif
```

```
/**
 * @file Token.cpp
 */
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Token.h"

std::string opToString(Operator o) {
    std::string result;
    switch(o) {
        case ADD:
            result = "ADD";
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            result = "SUBTRACT";
            break;
        case MULTIPLY:
            result = "MULTIPLY";
            break;
        case DIVIDE:
            result = "DIVIDE";
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Token& t) {
    std::string type;
    switch (t.tag) {
        case OPERATOR:
            os << "OPERATOR: " << opToString(t.o) << std::endl;
            break;
        case OPERAND:
            os << "OPERAND: " << t.d << std::endl;
            break;
        case LPAREN:
            os << "LPAREN" << std::endl;
            break;
        case RPAREN:
            os << "RPAREN" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid token");
            break;
    }
    return os;
}

std::vector<Token> tokenize(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::vector<Token> result; 

    while (ss) {
        Token t;
        if (ss.peek() == ' ') {
            ss.get();
            continue;
        }
        if (isalnum(ss.peek())) {
            ss >> t.d;
            t.tag = OPERAND;
        }
        else {
            char op;
            ss >> op;
            t.d = 0;
            if (op == '(') {
                t.tag = LPAREN;
            }
            else if (op == ')') {
                t.tag = RPAREN;
            }
            else if (op == '*') {
                t.o = MULTIPLY;
                t.tag = OPERATOR;
            }
            else if (op == '/') {
                t.o = DIVIDE;
                t.tag = OPERATOR;
            }
            else if (op == '+') {
                t.o = ADD;
                t.tag = OPERATOR;
            }
            else if (op == '-') {
                t.o = SUBTRACT;
                t.tag = OPERATOR;
            }
            else {
                throw std::logic_error("Invalid token");
            }
        }
        result.push_back(t);
    }
    result.pop_back();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `(tokens[i] >= '0'` What is `tokens[i]`?  Is it a `char`?  From the posted code, `tokens[i]` is a `Token`.

Comment: i see, but my question is how do i convert that token to a char.

Comment: Please post `Token`.

Comment: oh ok, token.h and cpp, give me a sec.

Comment: also updated the gdb link

Comment: What field in Token are you really trying to compare against? I see a double and two enums. It feels like you're using code you borrowed somewhere.

Comment: taken from program assignment

Comment: added part of the make

Comment: `double d;` in `Token` doesn't make sense since from the code it seems all that you want is a `char`. I think you're conflating two things...the _token_ and it's _value_.

Comment: @Szizzle2 -- *my question is how do i convert that token to a char* -- From what you posted, there is nothing that indicates *how* to convert `Token` to a char.  As mentioned already, it contains an `enum` an `Operator` and a `Tag`, and none of those items tells anyone, even us, *how* to turn that into a `char`.  If you had a `char` member variable in `Token`, then *maybe* that would give us an indication of what to do.  But basically you're asking us how to convert two totally unrelated things.

Comment: thats all I was given in the program, But i guess i can use the tag from the .h file then. Since thats the only thing i can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to convert that token to a character.  Dealing with characters is the job of the tokenizer, which has already done its work.  Stop thinking about characters and start thinking about OPERAND, OPERATOR, LPAREN, and RPAREN which are the kinds of tokens.

You evidently need something along the lines of

```
for (auto tkn : tokens) {        // was for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++){
  if (tkn.Tag == Tag::OPERAND) { //        if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){
    s.push(tkn.d);               //            s.push(tokens[i] - '0');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I only asked on how to start it so this answer was great, compared to the other person who answered too but this works perfectly with a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states the problem:

```
PostfixCalculator.cpp: In member function ‘virtual double PostfixCalculator::eval(std::vector<Token>)’: PostfixCalculator.cpp:15:19: error: no match for ‘operator>=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka Token}’ and ‘char’)
     if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){
                     PostfixCalculator.cpp:15:39: error: no match for ‘operator<=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits
>::value_type {aka Token}’ and ‘char’)
     if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9' ){
                                         PostfixCalculator.cpp:16:24: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka Token}’ and ‘char’)
       s.push(tokens[i] - '0');
```

`Token` is a user-defined datatype and the compiler needs to know how to work on the expression `A >= B` when `A` is of type `Token` and `B` is a `char`. You can define the operators `<` and `==` on the Token class to achieve something as follows:

```
bool Token::operator==(char c) const {
    return (char)d == c;
}

bool Token::operator< (char c) const {
    return (char)d < c;
}
```

But, I'll ask you to ruminate over what you actually intend to mean by doing a comparison between a `double` and a `char` because that's what your code seems to be doing on

```
tokens[i] >= '0'
```

I think you might want to re-think your `Token` class. From the code you shared, it seems like it's a *wrapper* over a character with some metadata attached to it to represent it's attributes. All through your code the there is just the mere usage of

```
if (isalnum(ss.peek())) {
    ss >> t.d;
    t.tag = OPERAND;
}
```

and

```
t.d = 0;
```

The `double` of `Token` doesn't seem to be ever being used up to its capacity and actual use of storing floating-point numbers with higher precision. All that is stored are plain digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct Token {
    enum class Tag : uint8_t { OPERATOR, OPERAND, LPAREN, RPAREN };
    static constexpr char OPERANDS[] = {'/', '*', '+', '-'};
    explicit Token(char);
    /** a numeric value -- only valid if the tag is OPERAND */
    char unit;
    /** the category of the token */
    Tag tag;
    char operator()() const;
};

Token::Token(char c): unit(c){
    if(std::isdigit(unit)){ //Numbers are for sure operands
        tag = Tag::OPERAND;
    } else if(unit == '('){
        tag = Tag::LPAREN;
    } else if(unit == ')') {
        tag = Tag::RPAREN;
    } else if(std::any_of(std::begin(OPERANDS), std::end(OPERANDS),
        [&](char c){return c == unit;})) {
        tag = Tag::OPERATOR;
        //Then classify what's the operator if required.
    }
}

char Token::operator()() const {
    return unit;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Token> tokenVector;
    std::string inp = "935*+";
    for(char c: inp){
        //Weed out whatever Token doesn't support
        if(c != ' ') {
            tokenVector.emplace_back(c);
        }
    }
    for(const auto& token: tokenVector){
        std::cout<<token()<<' ';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/hP38cdr5f) (used `C++17`):

```
9 3 5 * +
```

This is just a bare-bone example based off the question on achieving parity with a char.

Comment: updated the gdb link. Full program on there

Comment: Every file is written and correct except the PostfixCalculator.cpp file.